# How to force engineers to work with synced fork branches

Tags: github, deployment, continuous-integration, git-fork

We have a repository that many engineers are pushing changes to via a forked repo.
What happens is that many of them are just updating their fork locally, and it is never synced properly at github.

How do I force them to work with an updated fork at any time?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: Git is distributed, full stop. Figure out the process you want to use and then make it policy. Ideally, do this with developer buy-in. They'll be a lot more likely to follow the process if they've contributed to it, and you'll be a lot more likely to end up with a good one if you listen to your developers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a people problem, not a technology problem. Assuming you have already asked the appropriate questions to discover what their problem is with following the proper workflow, and made efforts to mitigate any process problems, your next step is to insist.

Write into the terms of work the provisions you expect to follow, such as:

- No local branch shall be more than a certain number of revisions behind the master when worked on
- A developer must sync with the remote repository every N days
- Deliverable code will only be accepted as an artefact produced from the master branch

Put anyone who does not comply with these terms on a Performance Improvement Plan. If they don't change their practices according to the PIP, fire them.